# Architect cloud services to work with VPN

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to think of architecture on Windows Azure that would allow me to achieve following:
 - Have cloud service (NOT VM) that would be accessible through VPN from my on-premise site
 - Preserve the ability to autoscale this cloud service
 - This services should not be accessible through public internet

The only thing I could think of is to create two cloud services Front End and Back End.  Set the Back End to use internal end point to communicate with Front End then hide Front End service through configuring Win Firewall to be accessible from my on-premise site.  This way I should preserve scalability of my Back End and also hide service from public internet access.

Does this make sense at all?  Is there a better way to do this on Azure without using VMs?

Comment: Do you still need to utilize the default Windows Azure load balancer?

Comment: Yes I would like to preserve default Windows Azure load balancer.

Comment: The real fix to this issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn690121.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same way you said:

Front-end: Windows Azure Web Sites

Back-end : Windows Azure Cloud Services (Worker Role), using a virtual network with a VPN to my on promises services.